# Convert from Set to List in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I have a Set of type `Set<WordPair>` & I want to convert it to List of type `List<String>` because I want to save it using `SharedPreferences` API in Flutter

Currently, my state looks like

```
final Set<WordPair> _saved = Set<WordPair>();
```

Now I want to save the `_saved` variable into `SharedPreferences`

If I do, `prefs.setStringList('saved', _saved.toList());` it gives me compilation error like

> [dart] The argument type 'Set' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. [argument_type_not_assignable]

How do I store complete `_saved` variable in `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are unable to save it in the Preferences even after converting it into a list is that you are trying to save `StringList` (`prefs.setStringList`) whereas your set is of type `WordPair`

A workaround for that could be,

```
prefs.setStringList('saved', _saved.map((WordPair wordPairItem) => wordPairItem.toString()).toList());
```

i.e converting each item into String and then save it as StringList

To your follow-up question in the comments:

> how do I convert from `List<String>` to `Set<WordPair>` in `initState`? As there is no `.toWordPair()` & wrapping up takes 2 args so Idk how to do it?

As per documentation, `WordPair` is `Representation of a combination of 2 words, first and second`. Therefore, you can break the String into two substrings and pass those 2 substrings in the respective argument positions.

**[Update]** (solution proposed by the Author of the follow-up question)
The solution can be found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719052/6141587)

Comment: Thank you, Dennis. It worked. Follow up, how do I convert from `List<String>` to `Set<WordPair>` in `initState`?

Comment: As there is no `.toWordPair()`  & wrapping up takes 2 args so Idk how to do it?

Comment: As per documentation, WordPair is Representation of a combination of 2 words, first and second.  Therefore, you can pass the first item of the list in the first argument and an empty String in the next argument.

Comment: Ahh tysm. Never would have thought of that :)

Comment: Just a question, did you also try `asString` method? I mean according to docs https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/english_words/latest/english_words/WordPair/asString.html, it should world.

Comment: Yes, I did try it. It gave an error for `asString` (`asString` isn't a function because its a getter) so I changed it to `toString`. It works without parentheses though :)

Comment: Oh, okay. Cool. I'm sorry I didn't try it on my console before answering the question.

Comment: No worries, Dennis. Actually, I have another error now, `Invalid argument(s): Words of WordPair cannot be empty. Received: 'classleg', ''` so that solution doesn't work

Comment: Break the String in to pieces and pass two sub-strings in the arguments.

Comment: Yes currently doing that, I'll edit the answer when done :)

Comment: Yea, but that's not an efficient solution and shouldn't be done in `initState()`

Comment: Where should I do it then? I want the data from preferences when I open the app & I think it should be done in `initState` only. I'm a noob to Flutter so Idk where else it should be done. Any solutions?

Comment: You should do it in `initState` but the solution which you proposed isn't so efficient. So you should first display the user a `CircularProgressBar` and perform this task in background thread/isolates(in case of the dart) But what's wrong with splitting String in two random substrings?

Comment: I did 2 random substrings but it made it display weirdly because what I'm saving is what I'm displaying. I'm using [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#0) codelab plus maintaining state using `SharedPreferences` to add & delete startup names. And when I used 2 random substrings it displayed weirdly like `HElloworld` instead of `HelloWorld` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185046/discussion-between-dennis-and-deadcoder0904).

Comment: Dennis, I have left a msg in chat