# Separate a PascalCase string into separate words using Dart?

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I have a word `HelloWorld` that I want to split as `Hello` & `World` so how do I do that in Dart?

Currently, I have -

```
String str = 'HelloWorld';
```

And I don't know how to go further?

I have tried `RegExp` like

```
words = str.split(new RegExp(r"[A-Z]"));
```

But it is not working. How do I separate `Hello` & `World`?

Comment: Try this `(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)`

Comment: Sadly, Dart does not have look-behind. It uses ECMAScript 5 RegExps.

Comment: @irn it does have i tried here on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and it's working. you can copy paste code i added in answer and check.

Comment: Ack. We have a discrepancy because Dart compiled to JavaScript uses the current JavaScript RegExp engine of the browser, but native Dart (what Flutter uses) is based on the ECMAScript 5 RegExp syntax (it's a port of the V8 regexp engine from a few years ago). So, technically, Dart compiled to JavaScript is too permissive, because *Dart* does not support look-behinds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to split before capital letters, except the first one.
Just splitting at capital letters (well, ASCII letters at least) is easy:

```
// Single character look-ahead for capital letter.
final beforeCapitalLetter = RegExp(r"(?=[A-Z])");
...
var parts = string.split(beforeCapitalLetter);
```

The problem here is that it splits before the first letter too, giving you an empty first element in the resulting parts.
You could just remove that, if you are certain it's there.

```
if (parts.isNotEmpty && parts[0].isEmpty) parts = parts.sublist(1);
```

Or, you can get clever with the RegExp:

```
// Matches before a capital letter that is not also at beginning of string.
final beforeNonLeadingCapitalLetter = RegExp(r"(?=(?!^)[A-Z])");
List<String> splitPascalCase(String input) =>
    input.split(beforeNonLeadingCapitalLetter);
```

Example results:

```
print(splitPascalCase("HelloWorld"));  // [Hello, World]
print(splitPascalCase("One")); // [One]
print(splitPascalCase("none")); // [none]
print(splitPascalCase("BFG9000")); // [B, F, G9000]
print(splitPascalCase("XmlHTTPRequest")); // [Xml, H, T, T, P, Request]
```

(You might want to consider whether the last thing is what you want).

Another option is to not *split*, but *match* the parts you want.

```
final pascalWords = RegExp(r"(?:[A-Z]+|^)[a-z]*");
List<String> getPascalWords(String input) =>
    pascalWords.allMatches(input).map((m) => m[0]).toList();
```

This extracts all words starting with one or more leading capital letters (or at the beginning of the string). If your string contains only letters, it should do about the same as the previous function. If it contains other things, then those are ignored.

```
print(getPascalWords("BFG9000")); // [BFG]
print(getPascalWords("XmlHTTPRequest")); // [Xml, HTTPRequest]
```

Which one to prefer depends on which strings you expect to get as input, and how you want to handle edge-cases: Adjacent capital letters? All capital letters? Empty string?

If its always the concatenation of one or more two-letter-or-longer words with the first letter capitalized, then it's only easy cases, and either method will work.

Edit: Since this was first posted, Dart RegExps have begun supporting look-behinds. With that, it's possible to use split as well by breaking between a lower-case letter and an upper-case letter, as [Serdnad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2330228/serdnad) says in a comment:

```dart
final _pascalWordsRE = RegExp(r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])");
List<String> getPascalWords(String input) => pascalWords.split(_pascalWordsRE);
```

This splits after a lower-case letter and before an upper case letter.

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough answer. I used the 2nd one :)

Comment: To not split capital abbreviations like HTTP, `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` checks that the next letter is uppercase, and the previous one was lowercase.

Comment: Thanks. Added option using lookbehind as well.

Answer (score 6):

**You can try this**

```
r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"
```

> Explanation

- `(?<=[a-z])` - Positive lookbehind. Matches any lowercase letter.
- `(?=[A-Z])` - Positive lookahead.Matches any uppercase letter.

  ```
  void main() {

     String str = 'HelloWorld';
     var words = str.split(new RegExp(r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"));
     print(words);
  }
  ```

Prints -> [Hello, World];

Comment: This was working fine in DartPad but for some weird reason, it was giving me an error in Flutter. I'm sure it must be an error on my side. Thanks though :)

Comment: It's an error in Flutter because Dart RegExps don't actually support look-behind, but Dart compiled to JavaScript (which DartPad uses) will use the JavaScript RegExp implementation. The native Dart RegExp implementation used by Flutter does not support features added to JavaScript RegExps after ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 3):

`titleCase` from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/recase
provides that (among many others)

```
var recase = ReCase(str);
print(recase.titleCase);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use Recase someday. For now, the accepted answer did the job :)

Comment: Lrn's answer is of course the best, but I thought ReCase is a good suggestion for the job. Came in handy several times already when there is a lot of re-casing like with code generation where you need file names, class names, imports, ... generated out of a single name in different casing.